# Why the size of this binary files are equal although they should not?

Tags: python, arrays, binary

By writing simple python script, I encoutered a weird problem: Two files with a different content have same size.

So, I have a two same list of some binary data, one in string, one in int:

```
char_list = '10101010'
int_list = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Then, I convert lists to bytearray:

```
bytes_from_chars = bytearray(char_list, "ascii")
bytes_from_ints = bytearray(int_list)
```

Printing this out, give me this result:

```
bytearray(b'10101010')
bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00')
```

but, this is ok.

Writing this data to disk:

```
with open("from_chars.hex", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytes_from_chars)

with open("from_ints.hex", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytes_from_ints)
```

And the **size of files are same**, but **files contains different data!**

```
ls -l:
```

[image: size of files]

hexdump of files:

[image: hexdump]

And my question is, why the size of file are equal? As I now, to write value of 0 or 1 we need 1 bit, and to write hex value of 30 or 31 we need 5 bits (1 1110 and 1 1111)

Comment: If you have an array of eight bytes then you're going to write 8 bytes to file. That's pretty important period after all if you read it back in you wouldn't want 8 bytes to have been written is 8 Bits And to only get one byte back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the value of `0` or `1` you do not need a single bit. How could you tell the difference between `3 = 11` or having two `1`?

You are writing in both cases an array of 8 bytes, Just in the first case your using the whole byte to write the char. 
Think of it as writing a word from the letters `0` and `1`, the word `1` is `0000 0001` , Without the `0s` in the start, you wont be able to tell what the word is.

Comment: Thanks! I miss that, I create bytes in byte_array() function.